# Load Adsense ads in ajax loaded pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, adsense

I have an audio streaming website and thus we need to keep the audio playing while the user navigate from one page to another page in the website. So to achieve the above, we need to load the content using Ajax. We are now trying to use Adsense ads in our website and observed that the ads doesn't get loaded when the content of an other page is being loaded using Ajax. So can you help how to use it. I tried using an separate html page where ads are placed and include it using iframe, this works but I am unsure if this is allowed by Adsense. Can you please confirm me if this approach using iframe is allowed or if there is any alternative workaround to load the ads.
I also tried to contact Adsense but I didn't find any contact details.

Answer (score 0):

How do you load ads currently? But generally the process will be the following:

1. Using ajax add `<ins class="adsbygoogle" ...>` elements where you want to see ad.
2. Once DOM is updated run `adsbygoogle.push({});` from JS to trigger ad load.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Will it cause any violation of Adsense TOS? Because i am really worried if they disable my account.

Comment: No, it doesn't violate AdSense TOS. You are allowed to change ad code as long as you don't inflate performance or confuse users: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en There are other sites that dynamically add ad tags to their pages, especially single-page app sites where there is no other way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply to my comment. As you have also asked how I am loading ads currently? I am loading the ads using the code snippet that Adsense has provided, I have directly placed those codes along with various contents where I want my ad. The contents are loaded using AJAX.